# Предположительно - как отличить наречие от вводного?

Tags: наречия, или, вводные-слова

ПРЕДПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНО, наречие и вводное слово

1. Наречие. То же, что «опираясь на предположения, на основании предположений, догадок».

Судить о причине этого взрыва можно только предположительно. А. Куприн, Сашка и Яшка.…Андрей знал, что действительное положение пеленгуемой рации будет всегда несколько в стороне от предположительно найденного и что погрешности при пеленгации могут иногда достигать нескольких километров. В. Богомолов, Момент истины.

2. Вводное слово. То же, что «вероятно, возможно, скорее всего». Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми. Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах см. в Приложении 2.

Книгу эту я буду писать, предположительно, всю оставшуюся жизнь, и все, что отныне будет (и кое-что, что доныне было) мною сочинено, может считаться входящим в нее. В. Войнович, Замысел. Я, предположительно, буду в Петропавловске-Камчатском в течение десяти дней.

Вопрос: почему в предложениях

•   •   *А я давно уже привык, что ни одна американская встреча, будь то дело или любовь, не обходится без предложения смягчить каким-нибудь напитком предположительно сожженную глотку.*

*Изучение опыта потока в деятельности хакеров проводилось в два этапа: с участием предположительно более компетентных и предположительно менее компетентных хакеров.*

*Предположительно бумаги будут возвращаться на рынок небольшими порциями ежедневно.*

*предположительно* - наречие?

Как научиться отличать наречие от вводного? В последнем предложении *предположительно* к какому слову относится?

Answer (score 3):

Во всех примерах "предположительно" является наречием в роли обстоятельства.

(1) А я давно уже привык, что ни одна американская встреча, будь то дело или любовь, не обходится без предложения смягчить каким-нибудь напитком  (предположительно сожженную глотку).

(2)Изучение опыта потока в деятельности хакеров проводилось в два этапа: с участием (предположительно более компетентных) и (предположительно менее компетентных) хакеров.

(3)Предположительно бумаги будут возвращаться на рынок небольшими порциями ежедневно.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

В предложениях 1 и 2  наречие входит в сочетание, не может быть выделено из него.

Структура  предложения 3 позволяет обособить наречие, но здесь на первый план выдвигается семантика сообщения. Скорее всего, это деловая бумага, в которой "предположительно" можно заменить  "в соответствии с предположением". Вводные слова "возможно, предположительно" не подходят к деловой лексике.

Таким образом,  при решении подобных задач учитывается как структура предложения,   так и семантика вводных сочетаний.